# Sumar datos de un array obtenidos de un WhereIn laravel 5.6

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Buen día amigos, tengo esta duda de como sumar estos elementos sacados de varias consultas
El resultado que me muestra es este:

```
[{"s1":15},{"s2":12},{"s3":5},{"s4":7}]
```

Lo que necesito es sumarlos para después pasarlos a una view.

Este es mi controlador

```
//Se consulta cada respuesta con funcion al ID del usuario
        $s1 = DB::table('preguntas as p')
        ->join('respuestas as r', function($on){
            $on->on('p.id_preguntas','=','r.id_preguntas');
        })
        ->join('usuario as u', function($join){
            $join->on('p.id_usu', '=', 'u.id_usu');
        })
        ->select(DB::raw('SUM(respuesta1) as s1'))
        ->where('u.id_usu','=',"1")
        ->whereIn('p.preguntas',['A','G','M'])
        ->first();
        //respuesta 2

        $s2 = DB::table('preguntas as p')
        ->join('respuestas as r', function($on){
            $on->on('p.id_preguntas','=','r.id_preguntas');
        })
        ->join('usuario as u', function($join){
            $join->on('p.id_usu', '=', 'u.id_usu');
        })

        ->where('u.id_usu','=',"1")
        ->whereIn('p.preguntas',['B','H','N'])
       // ->where('p.preguntas','=','A')
        ->select(DB::raw('SUM(respuesta2) as s2')) 
        ->first();   
        //repuesta3
         $s3 = DB::table('preguntas as p')
        ->join('respuestas as r', function($on){
            $on->on('p.id_preguntas','=','r.id_preguntas');
        })
        ->join('usuario as u', function($join){
            $join->on('p.id_usu', '=', 'u.id_usu');
        })

        ->where('u.id_usu','=',"1")
        ->whereIn('p.preguntas',['C','I','O'])
       // ->where('p.preguntas','=','A')
        ->select(DB::raw('SUM(respuesta5) as s3')) 
        ->first();   
        //respuesta4
        $s4 = DB::table('preguntas as p')
        ->join('respuestas as r', function($on){
            $on->on('p.id_preguntas','=','r.id_preguntas');
        })
        ->join('usuario as u', function($join){
            $join->on('p.id_usu', '=', 'u.id_usu');
        })

        ->where('u.id_usu','=',"1")
        ->whereIn('p.preguntas',['D','J','P'])
       // ->where('p.preguntas','=','A')
        ->select(DB::raw('SUM(respuesta4) as s4')) 
        ->first();   

        $arr = array($s1,$s2,$s3,$s4);
        //    list($a[0],$a[1],$a[2],$a[3]) = $s;
       return $arr;
        //  return $s1;
```

Intente de varias maneras con arrays pero no he podido realiar esta suma, no si para este tipo de definición de array sea distinto

he visto que muchos en los arrays lo tienen distinto a este.

gracias por la ayuda

EDIT---

A lo que me refiero, a groso modo estoy haciendo un sistema de encuestas (pequeño) pero lo que quiero es que estos valores que me arroja son los que el usuario ya ingreso, y este mismo necesito sumar, osea `15+12+5+7` y que lo guarde en X variable, es por eso que en  `$arr = array($s1,$s2,$s3,$s4);` es lo que dio de resultado de todas las consultas ya puestas mas arriba y como resultado esto me da `[{"s1":15},{"s2":12},{"s3":5},{"s4":7}]` necesito que me ayuden en esta parte a sumar estos resultados (ojo que no son resultados estaticos)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En vista que tienes un array de objetos y considerando que estas trabajando sobre PHP, puedes recorrer y traer cada objeto. También obtener las llaves dinámicamente a través de la función `key()` para conocer el valor correspondiente y así acumular en la variable `$sum`.

```
$sum = 0;

foreach ($array as $key => $object) {
    $k = key($object);
    $sum += $object->{$k};
}

echo $sum;
```

Muchas gracias lois6b por la recomendación.

Comment: Hola Silvio. Gracias por aportar. Para que la respuesta sea de más calidad y ayude no solo al OP si no a más usuarios, por favor explica cómo funciona. Mira [answer] para más info. un saludo

Comment: en Efecto Silvio le hice un pequeño cambio pero me ayudaste a la parte de la logica, ya que como tal el array era variable dependiendo de la respuesta del usuario, entonces la tuya fue mas acertada a mi parecer asi quedo, `foreach($colr as $colr)
        {
            foreach ($colr as $value) {
               $r += $value;
            }
        }`

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar Object.values para obtener los valores y luego sumarlos

```js
var array = [{
  "s1": 15
}, {
  "s2": 12
}, {
  "s3": 5
}, {
  "s4": 7
}];
var suma = 0;
array.forEach(function(current) {
  suma += Object.values(current)[0];
})
console.log('Suma: ', suma);
```

Comment: los datos son dinamicos no son como tal estaticos, osea que ´$s1,$s2,$s3,$s4´ cambian todo el tiempo dependiendo del usuario, aun asi funciona su coloco los ´$s1,$s2,$s3,$s4´ dentro del ´var array´?

Comment: no se entiende tu pregunta, mejora tu pregunta porfavor, para que te puedan ayudar la comunidad

Comment: agregue mas info, espero que se ente inda bien

Comment: y en eloquent como seria? porque me marca error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting '('`